# apex:inputField Binding Value not updated

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, visualforce

I am working with **Apex controller** and Visual Force page.
Inside of the vf page I had a data table and each row of that table binds to a value from a list that generated from the controller
example code:

```
<apex:dataTable value="{!List}" var="item"  styleClass="class1" >
...
<apex:column headerValue="Header1">     
    <apex:outputpanel rendered="{!NOT((a=='true'))}">
    <div class='estimate-name-column'>                          
        <apex:inputField value="{!item.Name}" required='true' rendered="{!(a=='false')}"/>
         </div>          
    </apex:outputpanel>     
</apex:column>  
...
</apex:datatable>
```

As you can see, I was trying to hide some inputFields base on some conditions.

However, there was a problem. If I do the above, those inputFields who get rendered were not binded correctly. After submited the form with this data table, inside my controller all the records' in list `Name` are `null`. Even though I saw the 'Name' was posted in http request.

I am guessing is render interfere with the binding? because if I remove the rerendered conditions and display all `InputField` I can get the values inside the controller after submitting form

any ideas what happened?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I recall correctly an apex tag must be present on the page in order to be rerendered.

In other words - something (maybe as simple as `<span id="long:generated:salesforce:id"></span>`) must be in HTML in order for later AJAX updates to inject new content into the placeholder. If it's not rendered, it will stay not rendered.(1)

Instead of `rendered` try to move your condition to `style`or `styleclass` attributes. Something like

```
<apex:inputField value="{!item.Name}" 
    required="{!a=='false'}" 
    style="display:{!IF(a=='false','inline', 'none')}"/>
```

`visibility:hidden` (if you want them to occupy their space but not be seen) or `display:none` (to have them appear to be completely not there. See also [What is the difference between visibility:hidden and display:none?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone)

---

Footnote:

(1) unless of course you'll rerender a tag that contains "this" tag (something higher in the XML).

Comment: Thank you! That is exactly how I did to solve the problem. I did the show/hide through css!